# Is it possible to install multiple instance of ArcGIS Portal on the same machine?

Tags: installation, license, arcgis-portal, virtual-machine

For sandboxing purposes, I'd like to be able to test something on a clean instance of Portal, without taking down the portal instance that my team members are using.

Is it possible to create another instance of Portal on the same machine, or am I going to have to spin up a new machine?

Comment: Changing ports would be a significant undertaking (completely unsupported) and is unlikely to work. Standing up a new VM is trivial in comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a response from Esri, no, it is not possible to configure multiple instances of Portal on the same machine.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this forum post [Multiple Portal instances](https://community.esri.com/thread/203785-multiple-portal-instances) it isn't. However, you can approach it differently to achieve the result of access for additional team members.

> Rather than 3 Portals, why not use Groups and security measures? There's also the GEO-Jobe tool, Mapfolio, that lets you build different landing pages for different groups. Your sharing the same server & datastore so it sounds like all you want to do is separate out access and sharing?

[Installing multiple ArcGIS Web Adaptors](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/web-adaptor/latest/install/iis/install-multiple-arcgis-web-adaptors-iis.htm)

> Multiple ArcGIS Web Adaptors can be installed on the same machine at the same time. The installation can also be repeated on separate machines. The steps below will guide you through the process.

Comment: I don't think that the forum post referenced answers the question as to whether it's possible. In that forum post, an alternative approach is recommended based on the specific scenario identified.

The OQ doesn't have anything to do with the web adaptor.